# IOS: Navigation Bar - Reload View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, reload, navigationbar

Is there any method to be released when we return to a viewcontroller from navigation bar?

I want to reload the NIB when I return to the screen from the navigation bar.

Is it possible?

thanks

Comment: so what you have in your rootView.xib to reload it is tabelView?

Comment: why do you want to reload the nib? maybe you don't need it and can you what is required in a different way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at `viewWillAppear:animated` and `viewDidAppear:animated` methods in `UIViewController`. They are called every time a view controller is pushed to display.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // Reload your data here, and this gets called
    // before the view transition is complete.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Reload your data here, and this gets called
    // after the view transition is complete.
}
```